# Unable to search item from "ebay.co.uk" while its available if search through Ebay Api

Tags: php, ebay-api

Thanks in advance.
when I search an item by item id `181856529922` from `GetItemStatus` api of ebay using following [url](http://open.api.ebay.com/shopping?callname=GetItemStatus&responseencoding=XML&appid=urappid&siteid=0&version=967&ItemID=181856529922), I get the status that item is active and ending date is many days later from today. Can anyone explain why ebay is giving an item in api result which is no more available in ebay search.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the items from ebay.co.uk i was using **shopping api** of ebay. It returns all the items including those which have been delisted by seller. So best possible solution for this problem is to use **Finding Api** of ebay which returns only available listings.